# detecting/tracking nano particle

Tags: nanotechnology, magnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

I am new to nano-sized particles and conducting a very simple experiment using nano particles. In my experiment I have nanomagnetic particles inside water and they are moving due to applied magnetic field. I am looking for a method to track or detect the motion of nano particles. Is there any easy way?

Comment: Umm, with your eyes would be simplest... Otherwise there's lots of instrumental methods, but it would depend on particles.

Comment: One particle? Mass flow??

Comment: it is superparamagnetic iron oxide nano powder. Actually I want to study morion if a single particle. But if they dont interact for better observation, I can use cluster too.. I dint know that ine can see nano partivles with naked eye.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to do nanoparticle tracking, although I'm not sure they will exactly apply to your system.

[**Dynamic light scattering**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_light_scattering) or DLS has been used to get the distribution of nanoparticle sizes in solution/suspension over time. Generally, the data gives information on the ensemble, not single-particle tracking.

[**Nanoparticle tracking analysis**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanoparticle_tracking_analysis) or NTA also relies on scattered light, but gives frame-to-frame analysis of each particle's trajectories.

There are other related techniques... Another approach is to create an **Anti-Brownian ELectrokinetic** (ABEL) trap - to monitor the particle or protein dynamics and apply forces to push it back. This technique was developed by the [Moerner lab at Stanford](https://web.stanford.edu/group/moerner/sms_trapping.html), for example [*Acc. Chem. Res.*, **2012**, 45 (11), pp 1955–1964](http://doi.org/10.1021/ar200304t)